# SQL WITH not working

Tags: sql

I have created a query but it is not working. Can anyone explain this to me? Thanks!

```
WITH    rows AS
    (
    SELECT   *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY dtDeliveryDate) AS rn
    FROM    TCheckRecipient
    )

select avg(avarage) from(     
SELECT TCheck.iCheckId, AVG(DATEDIFF(minute, mc.dtDeliveryDate, mp.dtDeliveryDate))  as avarage
FROM    rows mc
left join TCheck on TCheck.iCheckId = mc.iCheckId

JOIN    rows mp
ON      mc.rn = mp.rn - 1
group by TCheck.iCheckId
)
```

When I was doing

```
WITH    rows AS
        (
        SELECT   *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY dtDeliveryDate) AS rn
        FROM    TCheckRecipient
        )

SELECT TCheck.iCheckId, AVG(DATEDIFF(minute, mc.dtDeliveryDate, mp.dtDeliveryDate))  as avarage
FROM    rows mc
left join TCheck on TCheck.iCheckId = mc.iCheckId

JOIN    rows mp
ON      mc.rn = mp.rn - 1
group by TCheck.iCheckId
```

It works well.
But when I try to make the average of those returns, and I can not,
I'd be happy if someone would answer me how to do it thanks

Comment: What's the error you get? It's likely you need to put an alias on the subquery, i.e. after the closing bracket, just put, for example, "A" so that the inner query has a reference in the outer query

Comment: `group by TCheck.iCheckId
)When I was doing`` ?

Comment: "It's not working" is not a very good description. Does it not compile, does it throw an error, does it give unexpected output?

Comment: that is not CTE problem - you need to apply alias to subquery

Answer (score 4):

I'll put an answer in so that my comment has more clarity. You might just need to alias the inner query.

```
WITH    rows AS
    (
    SELECT   *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY dtDeliveryDate) AS rn
    FROM    TCheckRecipient
    )

select avg(avarage) from(     
SELECT TCheck.iCheckId, AVG(DATEDIFF(minute, mc.dtDeliveryDate, mp.dtDeliveryDate))  as avarage
FROM    rows mc
left join TCheck on TCheck.iCheckId = mc.iCheckId

JOIN    rows mp
ON      mc.rn = mp.rn - 1
group by TCheck.iCheckId
) A
```